# Fetch the last record by date in SwiftData

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have a @Model class that has an array of items which is also persisted in the database with a relationship. Is there a way to fetch the last record by date at the database level instead of fetching all records and then getting the max date

here is what I am doing now and it is slow and I am looking for a better way

```
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>(predicate: #Predicate {$0.tag?.persistentModelID == id}, sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.date)])
 let items = try! modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
                    let lastItem = items.last!
```

I tried with `fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1`, but it did not work and it was giving me some random item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reverse sort order with a fetch limit to only fetch the latest object

```
var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>(predicate: { 
    $0.tag?.persistentModelID == id 
}, sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)])
fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1
```